# Jscape SFTP/FTP upload to root dir fails

Tags: java, upload, ftp, sftp

I have been having an FTP issue using the com.jscape.FileTransfer API that I haven't been able to make sense for quite sometime. Here's my code:

```
public void do FTPTest() {
    FileTransfer f = protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("FTP") ? new FtpTransfer(ftpHost, userName, password, new Integer((int) port)) : (protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("SFTP") ? new SftpTransfer(
        ftpHost,
        userName,
        password,
        new Integer((int) port)) : null);
    try {
        f.connect();
        f.setAuto();
        System.out.println(f.getDir());
        f.upload("test".getBytes(), "ktest1.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code simply connects to an FTP/SFTP server and uploads a file called "ktest.txt"

My issue happens when I try to upload files to the base directory of the FTP/SFTP site.

Case 1: Connecting to FTP site 'A'

```
f.getDir() --> '/'
f.upload() --> SUCCEEDS
```

Case 2: Connecting to SFTP site 'B'

```
f.getDir() --> '/'
f.upload() --> FAILS (with permission denied error)
```

However,

Case 3: Connecting to SFTP site 'B'

```
f.getDir() --> '/'
f.setDirUp()
f.getDir() --> ''
f.upload() --> SUCCEEDS
```

Notice how it works when I do a setDirUp()

If i try to do the same on site A,

Case 4: Connecting to FTP site 'A'

```
f.getDir() --> '/'
f.setDirUp() (permission denied error)
```

All cases succeed if a do a setDir('testFolder') before uploading the file. i.e. a dir that is not in the base dir.

I don't understand how doing a setDirUp from '/' --> '' lets you upload a file to the base directory. What happens when you do an UP from '/'. What is '' ?

And how uploading to '/' works for some FTP sites.

BTW both FTP sites lets me upload files to the base dir without any issues using a client like WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that base dir `/` is not allowed for upload operation. When you do `setDirUp()` FTP server moves to back to default directory which is allowed for FTP transfer. Try to upload something to `/` with some GUI FTP client and see if it works.

Comment: I can upload files fine to '/' using an FTP client.

Comment: Whats even weird is that, when I do a getDirListing() on '/' or '', it gives me the same contents. So I don't get how it magically works after doing the setDirUp().

Comment: I'm assured this is casued by the setup of this particular FTP/SFTP server. Can you just try to do the same on any other public FTP/SFTP server with anonymous access and confirm that problem persists.

Comment: I agree with the possibility that its a server setup issue, but I'm trying to write code that will accept any server,username,password as parameter. So I'm trying to figure out the root of the problem. And yes, it does work for a few FTP/SFTP sites without issues. The one im working on right now doesn't have anonymous access. Thanks

Comment: I was initially under the impression that jscape misunderstands '/' to be the base dir of the linux box (which would obviously give you a permission denied error).. but i was confused how it works for some servers which let me write to '/'

Comment: @kiran.gilvaz I think you should not care about this one server with setup issue. If it works for other servers - your code is bugfree. If you can reproduce this problem on other servers just give us more details on it.